# Equivalency of filtering after left join vs left joining a right filtered data set

Tags: sql

Are the two sql statement equivalent?

```
select a.accountid, b.attribute1
from account as a
left join dataset1 as b
on a.accountid= b.accountid
where b.attribute2= 'TEST';
```

as opposed to:

```
select a.accountid, b.attribute1
from account as a
left join (select * from dataset1 where attribute2= 'TEST') as b
on a.accountid= b.accountid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries give different results because the first is effectively an `inner join` -- the `where` clause undoes the outer join.

The syntax that you are looking for is:

```
select a.accountid, b.attribute1
from account a left join
     dataset1 b
     on a.accountid = b.accountid and b.attribute2 = 'TEST';
```

Answer (score 3):

The queries may give different results

The first query will fetch ONLY THE ACCOUNTS which do have a corresponding dataset1 AND dataset1.attribute2 is 'TEST' (since you're filtering the entire result-set by using a WHERE clause)

The second query will give you ALL THE ACCOUNTS, just that b.attribute1 column will be non-null only if a matching dataset1 row is found